# Why it is not returning grade with return type char?

Tags: java, return

I have started learning Java again. I am having problem displaying the char data type return value. Everything working expect this one. It should be able to display the grades as A B C D but it is blank. Can someone help me find the error and fix the problem? Some suggested that I can get it work using System.out.println("A"); before return 'A. I tried but it is not working. I searched in SF but could not find solution for exact problem. Thank You in advance.

```
package score;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author rabin
 */
public class Score {
    static double earnedPoints, possiblePoints, pointsPercent;
    static char grade;
    //static String name;
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int testNumber;

        String stuName;
        // TODO code application logic here
        System.out.println("How many tests were given?");
        Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        testNumber = input1.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter Student's Name");
        Scanner nameInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        stuName = nameInput.next();
        if (stuName.contains(" ")){
            System.out.println("This field should not contain spaces");


        }
        pointsEarned(testNumber);
        letterGrade(pointsPercent);
        displayResult(stuName, pointsPercent, grade);
    }
    public static double pointsEarned(int testNumber){

        System.out.println("Enter Points Earned.");
        Scanner pointsInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        earnedPoints = pointsInput.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter Possible Points.");
        Scanner possibleInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        possiblePoints = possibleInput.nextDouble();
        pointsPercent = ((earnedPoints / possiblePoints) * 100);
        return pointsPercent;
    }
    public static char letterGrade(double percentage){
        if (percentage >= 90 && percentage <= 100){
            System.out.println("A");
            return 'A';
        }
        else if (percentage >= 80 && percentage < 90){
            System.out.println("B");
            return 'B';
        }
        else if (percentage >= 70 && percentage < 80){
            System.out.println("C");
            return 'C';
        }
        else if (percentage >= 60 && percentage < 70){
            System.out.println("D");
            return 'D';
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("F");
            return 'F';
        }


    }
    public static void displayResult(String name, double percentage, char grade){
        System.out.println("Result");
        System.out.println("Name: " +name);
        System.out.println("Percent: " +percentage);
        System.out.println("Letter Grade: " +grade);



    }

}
```

Comment: You never assign anything to `grade`; you just return the value and discard it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `main` program you need to use your `static` variables to save the `return` values of your methods:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int testNumber;
        String stuName;
        // TODO code application logic here
        System.out.println("How many tests were given?");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        testNumber = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter Student's Name");
        //Scanner nameInput = new Scanner(System.in); you don't have to use another scanner variable to read inputs only one is enough
        stuName = input.next();
        if (stuName.contains(" ")){
            System.out.println("This field should not contain spaces");


        }
        pointsPercent = pointsEarned(testNumber); // save the return value of pointsEarned method in pointsPrecent
        grade = letterGrade(pointsPercent); //save the return value of letterGrade method in grade 
        displayResult(stuName, pointsPercent, grade);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't put the returned result in grade variable you have to use :

```
grade = letterGrade(pointsPercent);
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you've invoked the appropriate method but you're not assigning it to the `grade` variable.

assign the returned value to the `grade` variable like below:

```
grade = letterGrade(pointsPercent);
```